# disassamble function's start address in windbg

Tags: reverse-engineering, windbg, disassembly

I can find a function's start address in `gdb` with the `disas functionname` command.

How can I do the same with WinDBG?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561506(v=vs.85).aspx) command displays the symbols in all contexts that match the specified pattern `x [Options] Module!Symbol`.
The [uf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558942(v=vs.85).aspx) command displays an assembly translation of the specified function in memory `uf [Options] Address`
.

```
0:000> x handle!main*
00000000`00d17154 handle!mainret = 0n0
00000000`00d113f0 handle!main (int, char **)
00000000`00d11840 handle!mainCRTStartup (void)
0:000> uf main
handle!main [d:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\handle\handle\main.cpp @ 27]:
   27 00000000`00d113f0 55              push    rbp
   27 00000000`00d113f1 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
   27 00000000`00d113f3 81ece8000000    sub     esp,0E8h
   27 00000000`00d113f9 53              push    rbx
   27 00000000`00d113fa 56              push    rsi
```

Or simply using any address within function

```
0:000> uf 00d11465
handle!main [d:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\handle\handle\main.cpp @ 27]:
   27 00000000`00d113f0 55              push    rbp
   27 00000000`00d113f1 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
   27 00000000`00d113f3 81ece8000000    sub     esp,0E8h
   27 00000000`00d113f9 53              push    rbx
   27 00000000`00d113fa 56              push    rsi
   27 00000000`00d113fb 57              push    rdi
```